# How can these two `sed` commands be compressed into one?

Tags: sed

More a curiosity, but is there a way to compress these two sed commands into one?

```
sed -r '/sometext/!d' file.txt | sed -r '5,10!d'
```

The above gives me the 5th through 10th instances (6 in total) of a lines that contain "sometext".

The concatenation :

```
sed -r '/sometext/!d;5,10!d' file.txt
```

gives me only the lines that have "sometext" appearing in the 5th through 10th lines of original file.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
# make some test data
# seq 50 > /tmp/a
sed -i 's/.*/& sometext/;n' /tmp/a
# run existing commands
sed -r '/sometext/!d' /tmp/a | sed -r '5,10!d'
sometext
9 sometext
11 sometext
13 sometext
15 sometext
17 sometext
19 sometext
# run new command
sed '/sometext/H;$!d;g;s/\n/&&/5;s/.*\n\n//;s/\n/&&/6;s/\n\n.*//' /tmp/a
9 sometext
11 sometext
13 sometext
15 sometext
17 sometext
19 sometext
```

Explanation:

- Push lines of interest into the hold space (HS). `/sometext/H`
- Delete all other lines except the last. `$!d`
- Overwrite the last line with the contents of the HS. `g`
- Delete the first 5 lines. N.B. The first newline is an artifact from the `H` command. `s/\n/&&/5;s/.*\n\n//`
- Delete all but the first 6 lines. `s/\n/&&/6;s/\n\n.*//'`

N.B. The `5,10!d` commands means delete all but lines 5 to 10

Comment: I bow before your sed-fu; but I think I'll stick to the pipe for script readability!

Answer (score 1):

Not sed, but awk is quite readable:

```
awk '/sometext/ && ++count && 5 <= count && count <= 10' file.txt
```